# USB pins and SPI pins

Tags: microcontroller, digital-logic, i2c, spi, uart

I'm using this [WFI32E01PC](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/WSG/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/PIC32MZ-W1-and-WFI32E01-Family-Data-Sheet-DS70005425.pdf) module.

I've 2 questions from the datasheet.
I'm referring the table 3-1 from page 29 of the above datasheet.

1. I'm not planning to use USB pins of the module. Pins 4,5 & 6. Hence, according to section 3.2.5 unused I/O pins, on page 35, I am planning to configure the pins 4,5 and 6 as output and drive low. They will not be connected and left floating. Am I right in doing so? Or should I connect some pull-down resistor on those pins after configuring them as output and driving low?
2. I need two SPI peripherals and 2 UART peripherals. In the table 3-1, I see I have SPI1 peripheral available. But SPI2 is not available. But I see SCK2 available in pin 43. What about the other SPI pins for the SPI2? They seem to be missing?

I also read about the PPS feature in page 217. Should I just consider the pins having the PPS feature and configure them as SPI for my second SPI peripheral in the module?

Answer (score 2):

*Question 1*

> 3.2.5 UNUSED I/O PINS
>
> **Unused I/O pins must not be allowed to float as inputs**. They can be **configured as outputs and driven to a logic-low state**.
> Alternatively, inputs can be reserved by **connecting the pin to VSS through a 1 kΩ to 10 kΩ resistor and configuring the pin as an input**.
>
> 3.2.5.1 GPIO Pins/PPS Functions
>
> Most of the WFI32E01 module pins can be configured as GPIOs pins or for PPS functionality. To find the functionality supported by each of these GPIOs, refer to Table 3-1.
> It is recommended that a series resistor be added on the host board for all GPIOs. The value of the series resistor depends on the actual pin configuration. These resistors must be placed close to the module. Figure 3-
> 11 illustrates the placement of series resistor

Source: [datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/WSG/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/PIC32MZ-W1-and-WFI32E01-Family-Data-Sheet-DS70005425.pdf)

---

*Question 2*

SPI1 is available via dedicated pinout, or configurable via PPS (Peripheral Pin Select). SPI2 is only available via PPS (except for SCK2, which is a dedicated pin).

[image]

Check section **13.4.3 CONTROLLING PERIPHERAL PIN SELECT** how to use PPS.

> I also read about the PPS feature in page 217. Should I just consider the pins having the PPS feature and configure them as SPI for my second SPI peripheral in the module?

Yes, exactly.